# Getting Error 'HasFile' is not a member of 'FileUpload' VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I randomly get an error saying HasFile is not a member of FileUpolad. 
I'm using a file upload button to upload images to a server. This usually runs; however, every once in a while it errors out. Sometimes the error is caught by Visual Studio during run time, other times it will be a Server Error in Application. Compilation Error when I load the page in debug mode. I've check dependencies and everything seems to be fine. Even the IntelliSense brings up HasFile with I am writing the code.

Usually re-writing the line or restarting Visual Studio resolves the issue, but it keeps coming up randomly.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to help you we need to see what's going on and be able to reproduce the problem ourselves. Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code, along with the **exact** error message that you get and on what line it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to figure out what the problem was. Since it was my first time doing this I had a test class in the solution. The test class was named FileUpload. Rookie mistake. I can't believe I didn't catch that earlier!